# The product image is not displaying in the product details page in magento2

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

The product image not displaying in product details page when it is loading but not display image. please find the http://i.prntscr.com/Sm8MZzxARWmH-KFfaIq2Fw.png
link. Can you please help me?

Comment: have you checked browser console  logs?

Comment: Hi Kunj,  I have checked browser console logs. But I can't find the problem. Can you please help me?

Comment: can you share website URL?

Comment: http://18.236.62.250/magemigration/dr-kings-natural-medicine-homeopathic-regional-allergies-southern-u-s-2-oz.html

Comment: Because of this code `<script type="text/javascript">    require([        'jquery',        'Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu'    ], function ($) {        $(".sw-megamenu").swMegamenu();    });</script>`  product images not loading. we are gettting `swMegamenu` not found error.

Comment: How to find this problem

Comment: Can you please help me what I am doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80907/discussion-between-kunj-and-dileep-kumar).

Comment: Hi @ Kunj, can you please help me?

Comment: Please open that chat

Comment: I have to search with Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu keyword. Next what I am doing?

Comment: Hi @ Kunj, can you please help me?

Comment: I have sent message in chat

Comment: Hi @ Kunj, Can you please help me with this task?

Comment: Hi, is that worked with `view.xml` file?

Comment: I didn't change any modifications on view.xml file I have changed the only gallery.phtml file only. Please let me know I want to change view.xml file?

Comment: yes you must  create/add  that file in your theme.